# Git format-patch for certain file format

Tags: git

When using git format-patch to generate patches, I only want to generate patches for certain formats such as "*.cpp" file, is it possible to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reading https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html, my guess if you would need to split the diff(s) to only contain the files you care about.  Otherwise you would be generating a patch that does not correspond to a commit.

Comment: Actually I want to exclude those commits containing certain files.